# wso2 DSS Dynamic Data Source Switching

Tags: wso2, datasource, wso2-data-services-server

I have an Rest service build on wso2  Dss. This Rest call an SQL query link to an datasource.

I cannot find the way to switch on runtime the datasource. I want with the same service, do the same query on an different datasource that I can specified in parameter.

Thank for your help.
Best regards,
Nicolas

Answer (score 0):

You can make several DSS services with different datasource and make Proxy service in WSO ESB to balancing requests to your DSS services by parameter in url.